# Prove $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$, if $ab+ac\equiv 3\pmod 6$ then $b \not\equiv c \pmod 6$ by contraposition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove by contraposition:
>
> $(\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$) if $ab+ac\equiv 3 \pmod 6$ then $b
>  \not\equiv c \pmod 6.$

So, by contraposition，it is  $\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb Z,$ if $b \equiv c \pmod 6$, then $ab+ac\not\equiv 3 \pmod 6.$

No idea for next step

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please write your questions in the body, not just titles.

Answer (score 2):

If $b \equiv c$, then $$ab + ac \equiv 2ab \not\equiv 3 \pmod{6}$$ since $2ab$ is even and $3 + 6k$ is odd for any $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Said more structurally: the congruence $\!\pmod{\!6}$  *persists* $\!\pmod{\!2}$ where it yields a parity contradiction. I emphasize this viewpoint in my answer.

Comment: Sorry，b≡c (mod 6) i guess is equal to b=c+6k, and I can not understand why c=b at here. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Congruences $\!\!\pmod{\! 6}$ *persist* $\!\!\pmod{\! 2}\,$ so $\, \color{#c00}{c\equiv b}\,\Rightarrow\,  0\equiv ab\!+\!a\color{#c00}b\equiv 3\equiv 1\,$ contradiction

**Remark** $ $ This persistence of congruences is familar from decimal arithmetic where we frequently compute the parity of an integer from its units digit $\,d\,$ i.e. $\, n\equiv d\pmod{\!10}\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv d\pmod{\!2}$

The proof that congruences always *persist* mod factors of the modulus is easy, namely $$\,a\equiv b\!\!\pmod{\!mn}\,\Rightarrow\, \underbrace{m\mid mn\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid a-b}_{\large\text{$\it{transitivity}$ of divisibility}}\,\Rightarrow\,a\equiv b\!\!\pmod{\!m}$$

This basic property of congruences should be committed to memory as it is frequently applicable.

Comment: And the reason why you wouldn't answer the older version is....? Mind you I won't overrule your reversal, but I'm just curious. Be advised. There is a flag asking about the same thing. Naturally I will leave the decision to other moderatores.

Comment: @Jyrki I did not see your closure till after I posted my answer (network delay?). Since this question has better answers than the old, and since persisntence of congruences is something that deserves better exposure, I though it better to leave the newer version open (far fewer people read older answers).

Comment: Fair enough. ${}$

Comment: @Jyrki Maybe you missed that my answer was posted *before* I reopened it but *after* you closed it (see the timelne). Your closure didn't show till after I posted.